# Possible to scrape .onion sites?

Tags: onion-services

Has anyone successfully scraped/mirrored a site which is offered as a Tor Onion Service? If so, how did you manage? I've been researching this for a few days, and come up empty handed.

Comment: What do you mean by "a Tor site" and why would "scraping" it be any different from any other site?

Comment: Can you please describe what exactly do you want/intend to do? What is exact meaning of a "scraping" in your task?

Comment: By TOR site I am referring to a .onion domain. It's different from scraping a regular site based on the necessity of using a TOR browser to access. This includes I2P (I think that's the acronymn), and any other browser used to access .onion sites. You can't use tools such as Octoparse or Httrack to scrape data from .onion sites.

Comment: By scraping I am referring to the ability to pull data from .onion sites in a manner similar to the surface web.

Comment: Sorry for posting the reply as an answer Alexey... I'm still trying to get used to the stack exchange app

Comment: You can, you'd just need to find a way to get them to use a proxy or use transparent proxying. Lots of people are already doing this.

Comment: First you need to make a tor environment using 127.0.0.1:8118 and than scrape data it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Web sites which are offered Tor Onion Services (.onion domain) can be downloaded/mirrored/scraped like any other websites. You only need to tell your favorite tool to use the Tor software as a proxy. I usually use `wget` for such purposes. So I added the following lines to my `.wgetrc`:

```
use_proxy=yes
http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8118
https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8118
```

Then I just issue the command `wget http://bylu6d6nx3og7shy.onion/`. This downloads the `index.html`. For mirroring I would add the `-m` option and wget will download the complete site.